# Не конвертируется из .py файла в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Перепробовал все советы с интернета. Ничего не помогло.

Есть код:

```
from subprocess import check_output
from socket import gethostname, getfqdn
import psutil
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


def Subprocess_Command(*args):  # Вызов команды/сохранение команды в переменную
    return check_output(*args, universal_newlines=True, encoding='cp866')


def Hostname():  # Узнаем имя хоста
    try:
        h_name = gethostname()
    except Exception:
        h_name = 'Не удалось получить имя хоста'
    return h_name


def Domain():  # Узнаем домен(рабочую группу)
    return getfqdn().split('.', 1)[1]


def ping_server():  # Проверка соединения с сервером
    try:
        Subprocess_Command(['ping', '(...)'])
        return None
    except Exception:
        return 1


def Ip_Mac():  # Узнаем IP и MAC адрес
    interfaces = psutil.net_if_addrs()
    list_configs_interfaces = []
    list_valid_ip = []
    for interface in interfaces:
        for int_configs in interfaces[interface]:
            configs = int_configs
            if str(configs[0]) == 'AddressFamily.AF_INET':
                ip_add = configs[1]
                x = interfaces[interface]
                for i in x:
                    for y in i:
                        if str(y) == 'AddressFamily.AF_LINK':
                            mac_add = i[1]
                            str_var = f'{str(interface)} : {str(ip_add)}, {str(mac_add)}'
                            list_configs_interfaces.append(str_var)
                            list_valid_ip.append(str(ip_add))
    return list_configs_interfaces, list_valid_ip


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Developer = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Developer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 585, 261, 16))
        self.Developer.setObjectName("Developer")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 585, 800, 16))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(63, 197, 255);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.info = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.info.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 16))
        self.info.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(63, 197, 255);")
        self.info.setObjectName("info")
        self.Hostname0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hostname0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 191, 16))
        self.Hostname0.setObjectName("Hostname0")
        self.Hostname0.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Domain0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Domain0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 50, 16))
        self.Domain0.setObjectName("Domain0")
        self.Domain0.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Interfaces0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Interfaces0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 80, 16))
        self.Interfaces0.setObjectName("Interfaces0")
        self.Interfaces0.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 161, 16))
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0.setObjectName("Connecting_to_the_server0")
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 544, 800, 41))
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
                                    "background-color: rgb(73, 225, 255);")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 30, 81, 18))
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(23, 189, 255);")
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server.setObjectName("btn_connecting_to_the_server")
        self.btn_update = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_2)
        self.btn_update.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 550, 20))
        self.btn_update.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(23, 189, 255);")
        self.btn_update.setObjectName("btn_update")
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 30, 101, 16))
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setText("")
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setObjectName("Connecting_to_the_server1")
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Hostname1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Hostname1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(219, 50, 581, 16))
        self.Hostname1.setText("")
        self.Hostname1.setObjectName("Hostname1")
        self.Hostname1.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Domain1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Domain1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 731, 16))
        self.Domain1.setText("")
        self.Domain1.setObjectName("Domain1")
        self.Domain1.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.Interfaces1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Interfaces1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 60, 16))
        self.Interfaces1.setObjectName("Interfaces1")
        self.Interfaces1.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.widget.raise_()
        self.Developer.raise_()
        self.info.raise_()
        self.Hostname0.raise_()
        self.Domain0.raise_()
        self.Interfaces0.raise_()
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0.raise_()
        self.widget_2.raise_()
        self.Connecting_to_the_server1.raise_()
        self.Hostname1.raise_()
        self.Domain1.raise_()
        self.Interfaces1.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Быстрый просмотр сетевых настроек"))
        self.Developer.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Разработчик: Ахмадеев Булат Наилевич"))
        self.info.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                     "       Программа создана специально для ..., для быстрого просмотра сетевых настроек."))
        self.Hostname0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя хоста (Имя компьютера):"))
        self.Domain0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Домен:"))
        self.Interfaces0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Интерфейс:"))
        self.Connecting_to_the_server0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Подключение к серверу:"))
        self.btn_update.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Обновить"))
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверить"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.btn_update.clicked.connect(self.update_info)
        self.btn_connecting_to_the_server.clicked.connect(self.conn_serv)

    def conn_serv(self):
        if ping_server() is None:
            self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setText('Присутствует')
        else:
            self.Connecting_to_the_server1.setText('Отсутствует')

    def update_info(self):
        self.Hostname1.setText(Hostname())
        self.Domain1.setText(Domain())
        list_interfaces = []
        str_interfaces = ''
        for elem in Ip_Mac()[0]:
            list_interfaces.append(elem)
            list_interfaces.append('\n')
        for i in list_interfaces:
            str_interfaces = str_interfaces + i
        self.Interfaces1.setText(str_interfaces)
        self.Interfaces1.adjustSize()

    # def save_info(self):


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Сам код работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На красоту не смотрите, моя задача сейчас просто конвертировать его в .exe.

Пытаюсь конвертировать в .exe файл командой:`pyinstaller 'файл'`. Вывод: Выдает ошибку, что он не нашел плагины PyQt5.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один из советов был добавить к команде `pyinstaller --exclude-module PyQt5 'файл'`.
Вывод: `pyinstaller` выполнил свою работу, папки dist и build создались, но файл.exe запускается(как консоль) и моментально закрывается.

Попробовал так: `pyinstaller --noconsole --exclude-module PyQt5 'файл'`.
Вывод: `pyinstaller` выполнил свою работу, папки dist и build создались, но при запуске файла.exe выдает это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи! На Mac OS заработало все отлично, но с Windows какие-то проблемы.

Использую версию Python 3.9. ОС Windows 10

Может проблема в версии Python'на? Или нужно попробовать виртуальный Python? Я уже не знаю что пробовать.

Comment: Если все установлено, то возможная причина из-за наличия кириллицы в пути до каталога с PyQt5

Comment: А исключение модуля PyQt5 из сборки (`--exclude-module PyQt5`), конечно, приведет к ошибке -- как он без модуля запустится? :) Возможно, у вас действительно проблема из-за русских букв в пути. Еще, проверьте что по тому пути к папке с плагинами есть что-то

Comment: Спасибо вам! И в правду из-за русских букв в адресе расположения. Такая мелочь, а потратил неделю на это. Никогда бы не подумал, что из-за этого может быть проблема…

Comment: @Bulat_Akhmadeev, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях ответили.

Проблема была в том, что в пути была кириллица. Пришлось создавать нового пользователя.